# Finding xpaths using cucumber and selenium for Salesforce automation testing

Tags: selenium, xpath, cucumber

Where is the best free tutorial online to describle how to determine relative xpaths?  I am working on a Salesforce project with Cucumber and Selenium, and we can only use xpaths (as opposed to ID or css) due to Salesforce's dynamic nature.  Best Cheat Sheets would also be appreciated.  Note:  Right clicking and copying the xpath does not work for this project.  We use the Chropath extension on Chrome, but it only works around 60% of the time.  I need to be able to hand script xpaths the other 40%. Note:  This is a Selenium IDE over Java framework, and only uses Chrome browser, so Firefox inspection tools won't work in this scenario.  Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many cheat sheets some of them are at top of google search results-

1. [PDF's cheat sheet to have them always handy](http://scraping.pro/5-best-xpath-cheat-sheets-and-quick-references/)
2. [another online best cheat sheet to have as bookmark](https://devhints.io/xpath)
3. [LeCoupa's collection on git hub](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14)